# Why am I getting Invalid config object on webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm learning webpack from a pluralsight course. I'm using the author's package.json file.

If I run just webpack command it runs fine.

If I run webpack-dev-server, I get the following:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, loaders?, noParse?, rules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["./utils", "./app.js"],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: 'node_modules',
                loader: 'jshint-loader'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
    }
}
```

My package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to run webpack2 with config for webpack1 - you need to make sure you have webpack1 globally installed since your course is on webpack1 - not webpack 2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with Webpack 2 you can update your webpack.config.js

You don't need the empty extension in Webpack 2, so where you have

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
}
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.es6']
}
```